# How can I stop this ugly font smoothing with custom fonts in CSS?

Tags: css, custom-font

I have some buttons my page using a custom font face using the CSS and files generated by the [Font Squirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

When the font's colour is black, they display fine...

[image: Black on green]

However, when I change the colour to something else, the text seems to have a smoothing that bleeds the characters into each other and generally makes the characters look too *thick*...

[image: White on black]

I've played around with `font-smooth` property and a few other things, but have been unable to get it to work...

I don't think it's too relevant but the CSS for these buttons are...

```
color: #FFFFFF;  
display: block;
padding: 1em 0.3em;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 10;
font-family: BebasNeueRegular,Arial,Sans-Serif;
font-size: 22px;
list-style: none outside none;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

The background is a separate element.

How can I get the white text to appear like the black text?

<sup>(It may be hard to tell the difference between the two, but my boss insists it is there.)</sup>

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas: Which browser(s)/OS? Does `text-align: left` or changing the `font-size` make any difference? Does `text-shadow` help? Did you try messing with the "Expert" Font Squirrel settings? Do other custom fonts have the same problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can try Cufon instead. http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

I have switched to using this when rendering needs to be as clean as possible.

Comment: @mu I tried `letter-spacing: 1px`, but it is too large a gap.

Comment: @thirtydot I tried all those things already and so far no good. I was hoping you'd come by and give me the answer :)

Comment: I haven't come across this problem before, despite regularly using Font Squirrel. Or maybe I have, but I simply didn't notice it.. :o

Comment: @thirtydot You can see the issue [here](http://dortracker.com/index.php). :) Thanks.

Comment: @alex: Using Windows 7, none of my browsers exhibit the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot Must be an OS X thing.

Comment: Looks fine on Linux too. But I had previously fought with the Appearance control panel for a little while in order to get my fonts looking sweet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that it's not a particularly well-made font. I concur with @thirtydot's suggestion of text-shadow. A 1px black-on-black text-shadow should thin the font out. Any browser that doesn't support text-shadow will be rendering the font horribly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

And remember that some html elements has bold as default, like h1, h2... When I use font squirrel to generate a font and use it with h1, for example, I always put:

```
font-weight: normal;
```